# Switch view controller works if no other buttons are pressed

Tags: swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I have a view that has a user input server info and on submit switches to another view. It works fine if they just hit submit. I have another button that is used to clear the saved server info if they wanted to change it at some point. The issue is that it doesn't work if the resetServerInfo button is pressed prior to the submit button.

User flow that works: Enter server name/Server IP -> testConnection -> submitServer -> Switches view controller

When it fails: clearServerInformation -> Enter server name/Server IP -> testConnection connection -> Submit -> Doesn't do anything

The code:

```
class serverSelect: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var serverNameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var serverIPField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var successLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var errorLabel: UILabel!



//Submit button - checks fields aren't empty, then saves info to core data
@IBAction func submitServer(sender: UIButton) {
    errorLabel.hidden = true
    if(!serverNameField.text!.isEmpty && !serverIPField.text!.isEmpty){
        saveName(serverNameField.text!, ip: serverIPField.text!)
        switchToViewController("userselect")
    }
    else {
        errorLabel.text = "Fields must contain data"
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }

}



//Calls deleteserverinformation on button click
@IBAction func resetServerInfo(sender: UIButton) {
    let result = deleteServerInformation()
    if(result){
        successLabel.hidden = false
        successLabel.text = "Server Information Reset"
    }
    else {
        errorLabel.hidden = false
        errorLabel.text = "Failed to delete. Try again."
    }
}



//Removes all server information stored in core data
func deleteServerInformation() -> Bool {
    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let coord = appDel.persistentStoreCoordinator

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Server")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
        try coord.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: context)
        return true
    } catch let error as NSError {
        debugPrint(error)
        return false
    }
}


//Clears old server information and commits new data to core data
func saveName(name: String, ip: String) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Server")
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Server",
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let server = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    server.setValue(name, forKey: "serverName")
    server.setValue(ip, forKey: "serverIP")

    do {
        let results =
            try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        let server = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        if(server.count != 0){
           deleteServerInformation()
        }
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}


//Call to switch view controller on successful submit
func switchToViewController(identifier: String) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}




}
```

I am new to swift so I imagine I am just missing some conceptual thing. I really don't have a good grasp on the core data stuff yet. From what I have read the view controller flow is all related to app delegate, so could it have to deal with how my deleteServerInfo is dealing with the app del AND my SaveServer also is dealing with it and when used one after another it causes issues? I'm sorry if I am way off, but it is the only thing I can think of that really changes between the two user interaction paths.

So basically the issue is the "submitServer" function runs fine and switches view over to userselect view controller when no other button is pushed in the view controller. However, if I press the button that triggers "resetServerInfo" first (which runs fine), when i click and run "submitServer" again it no longer switches view controllers.

Comment: Where exactly is the issue happening? Could you truncate your code please?

Comment: @kye The issue is happening at the function call switchToViewController("userselect")

Comment: Try printing out the text of both your `UITextFields` to ensure their not empty, your problem is most likely taking place there.

Comment: Nope. Both fields print out. And I can keep hitting submit and they will continue to keep printing, just never moves on from that.

Comment: Strange! Mind sharing your project?

Comment: I think I figured out my issue! I didn't fully understand navigation controllers and I only had a navigation controller for the userSelect view controller but I didn't have one for the serverSelect view controller. Once I added one to that view controller it worked!